# C# 3 new feature posts (and not about .Net 3.5 features)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, c#-3.0

There are a lot of new features that came with the .Net Framework 3.5. Most of the posts and info on the subject list stuff about new 3.5 features and C# 3 changes at the same time. But C# 3 can be used without .Net 3.5. Does anyone know of a good post describing the changes to the language? (Besides the boring, explicit official specs at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx) that is.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update: I can certainly understand. 
Eric Lippert has some more indepth posts..[Check them out](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/C_2300_/Lambda+Expressions/default.aspx).

---

I liked the series of posts by [scottgu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/08/new-c-orcas-language-features-automatic-properties-object-initializers-and-collection-initializers.aspx) on the new language features..
Some more info here as well http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/11/top-10-things-to-know-about-visual.html esp the section on language features.

Comment: Those aren't bad for intro-level. I sort of wanted in-depth discussion but just about C#3 features. Not C#3 features in the context of .Net 3.5. I know, lazy since I could just learn LINQ, etc., but it gets confusing when I run so many projects with different versions of things. Most do not use 3.5.

Answer (score 4):

There's a ["quick and dirty" list on my C# in Depth site](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BluffersGuide3.aspx) (which is also slightly tongue in cheek):

To respond somewhat to Charles Graham's post, I have an [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) about how applicable the language features are when targeting .NET 2.0:

Just as a blatant plug, if you're interested in language rather than framework, [C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/affiliate/idevaffiliate.php?id=876_230) is about as close to a "language only" book as I've seen. It's also divided into two parts (after the introduction): new features in C# 2, and new features in C# 3.

Comment: For going from C#2 to 3 Jon's book is just the one I would have suggested. Manning get the e-publishing stuff right too.

Answer (score 3):

Scott Guthrie has a [good series of blog posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/19/visual-studio-2008-and-net-3-5-released.aspx) that describe a lot of the improvements. Scroll down to "Language Improvements and LINQ".

[Lambda Expressions](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/08/new-orcas-language-feature-lambda-expressions.aspx)
[Anonymous Types](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/15/new-orcas-language-feature-anonymous-types.aspx?CommentPosted=true)
[Automatic Properties and object/list initializers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/08/new-c-orcas-language-features-automatic-properties-object-initializers-and-collection-initializers.aspx)
[Extension Methods](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/13/new-orcas-language-feature-extension-methods.aspx)
[Query Syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/21/new-orcas-language-feature-query-syntax.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing that I want to avoid though. The "...and LINQ" part. I would like a good post about lambdas and such, without the context of LINQ. A bit lazy, I know, since I need to learn LINQ eventually, just not yet...

Comment: In that section you'll see a blog post entitled "Lambda Expressions" which covers exactly what you want.

Comment: I haven't read Scott's blog, but all the things I have read about LINQ have concentrated on the language changes necessary to support it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Eric White's [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/pages/FP-Tutorial.aspx) on functional programming in C# 3.0

Answer (score 0):

That's one thing that I would concretely like to know myself.  The one thing that I can tell you is that a lot of the new features in C# 3.0 will actually work in a purely 2.0 application if you do multi targeting in VS 2008.  I know that extension methods are one such thing.

Comment: That's the situation I'm in on a few projects actually, and therefore why I asked the question.  :)

Answer (score 0):

here is a series of articles that helped me understand the new features quickly

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006/05/19/demystifying-c-30--part-4-lambda-expressions.aspx