# What is the difference between C# versions like ver 2.0 and ver 3.0?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:** 
>   [What are the correct version numbers for C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) 
>   [List of new features in C# 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174942/list-of-new-features-in-c2-0-3-0-and-4-0)

What is the difference between C# versions like ver 2.0 and ver 3.0?

Please help me explain in detail. What are the exact differences?

Comment: Certainly a dup; perhaps [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c) as a start?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174942/list-of-new-features-in-c2-0-3-0-and-4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many new features support the introduction of LINQ (they can be used in many different contexts, but they are very useful in the context of LINQ).

I strongly suggest you read Jon Skeet's *C# in Depth* for a detailed explanation of each new feature.

Answer (score 3):

From Jon Skeet's book *C# in Depth*, the web page is [**here**](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) for detail.

**C# 2,** introducing generics, nullable types, anonymous methods, iterator blocks and some other more minor features

**C# 3,** introducing implicit typing, object and collection initializers, anonymous types, automatic properties, lambda expressions, extension methods, query expressions and some other minor features